# GitHub feature branch

Tags: github

I have forked a repo with master branch . I have few changes here committed. I have to work a some feature now.how can I create a feature branch with latest from upstream and without the commits made to my master branch in my fork

Answer (score 1):

Very simple actually.

Create the new branch `feature`, fetch `upstream/master` and reset `feature`:

```sh
# fetch latest `master` from `upstream` remote
$ git fetch upstream master

# create and checkout new `feature` branch off your current branch (`master`)
$ git checkout -b feature

# reset `feature` branch to `upstream/master`
$ git reset upstream/master --hard
```

Comment: I suggest you to modify the above principle to **create a copy of your current `master`**, rename it to something else and then **`reset` your `master`** to avoid having to follow above steps for every future contribution.